# How to add date in google docs mobile app?

Tags: google-docs

Hi there on the Google docs website if you use `@Date` it automatically puts the current date. Is there a different command for the mobile app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the @date option in mobile app will open calendar for you to choose for the date. However, if you want to automatically put the current date you need to type @today

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on an Android device and an iPhone and it seems that this feature is not available for the Google Docs mobile app. According to [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10710316?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-and-edit-date-chips) it only gives you steps on how to do it on a computer.

To send feedback from the mobile app, tap the menu in the top-left of the app (top-right in a file), tap **Help & Feedback**, and then choose **Send Feedback** to write and submit your Feature request.